# Domain user asked to reauthenticate credentials after every log in

Tags: windows-server-2012, domain

Every time I log on to my PC, I get this popup message below.  I've been talking to our IT support company about it, and they say that I will have to clear the user off, and then log in again so that my user profile is set up again (it's a domain user).

However, I really don't want to do that, I've got hours of settings stored throughout different programs etc.  Is there a way to prevent this happening without having to clear my user profile down?

[image]

Comment: The error message sort of implies your profile isn't the problem at all; your (or the domain controller's) network settings are.

Comment: @grawity Hmm ok.  No one else is getting this message, and it used to be fine until a few weeks back - does that mean it could be a localised issue?  I can log into other PC's with the same user with no problem.

Comment: [Investigate.](https://www.wireshark.org/#download)

Comment: @grawity but does this run automatically on startup?  If not then it could miss the network activity at logon, as this popup is one of the first things to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT support spend 2 or 3 days working on this, and simply didn't get anywhere.  I've got a couple of colleagues with a similar situation, and IT support have worked on their PC's too in the past, no luck.

The only workaround is to decrease the domain user's security settings which is less then ideal, this effectively means their accounts won't lock out if wrong passwords are put in so they are liable to brute force attacks.

On my laptop, I ended up reinstalling windows.  Fresh install from USB, and everything was fine again, so it's definitely a problem with local PC, just seems impossible to determine what has corrupted.

If you get this problem and can fix it without reinstalling the OS, then please let me know!  Otherwise it seems to be the only option...

Comment: I'd have immediately started investigating DNS between the problem computer (your laptop) and the DC... You often get this kind of problem when attempting to domain join a computer where the client computer's DNS settings don't point to the DC as the primary DNS entry. This is why it's recommended to use the Windows Server DHCP server role as it passes the DC (if they're on the same box, which is often the case in smaller environments) IP to clients as their automatic primary DNS. Active Directory is heavily reliant on DNS.... this, IMO, points to a DNS problem on your client.